# Swift API Gateway key authorizatiion

Tags: swift, api, amazon-web-services, key, aws-api-gateway

I added a `key` to my API but I'm struggling to implement it in my app's code. I keep on getting a `message = Forbidden;`.

I've tested different methods but none is working. What's wrong here?

```
if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted) {

        let url = NSURL(string: "\(APIAddress)")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)

        request.httpMethod = "PATCH"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("\(APIKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.httpBody = jsonData

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                return
            }

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJSON = json {
                    let resultValue = parseJSON["success"]
                    print("result: \(String(describing: resultValue))")
                    print(parseJSON)
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Please note the method was working before activating the API key on API Gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not including all the headers that are required for a `POST` request.

[Here're the docs on how to construct a valid request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/making-http-requests/).

It seems like you're missing the `host` and `x-amz-date` headers.

Comment: The method was perfectly working before adding the `auth key` to the API

Comment: Okay my apologies you were right, I need 5 other headers when using `PATCH` with `Authorization header`.

Comment: That's great! `Content-Type`, `Authorization`, `host`, `x-amz-date`, and `Content-Length`?

Comment: Almost! `"Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header`. Do you have any experience with API Gateway with Swift?

Comment: A little bit, if you're having trouble, I recommend using their pod: https://cocoapods.org/pods/AWSAPIGateway

Comment: If my headers suggestion fixed your problem, would you mind marking my answer as correct? Cheers!